# Refactoring JS code in a functional way - closures

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, refactoring

I have the following repetitive code, for highlighting a section of html/css code, when a certain criteria is met. Namely, when I select three of the elements of the layout. As, It doesn't matter the order of selection, I have to repeat the code trice, to create listeners to each element.

I would like, thus, to refactor to a more functional style, as closures.

```js
for (var m=0; m < selectedDessert.length; m++){
    selectedDessert[m].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (buyImages.length + buyImagesDrink.length + buyImagesDessert.length === 3){
        footerStyle[0].classList.add("order");
        footerStyleSpan.innerHTML = "string";
        
    }});
    selected[m].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (buyImages.length + buyImagesDrink.length + buyImagesDessert.length === 3){
        footerStyle[0].classList.add("order");
        footerStyleSpan.innerHTML = "string";
    }});
    selectedDrink[m].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (buyImages.length + buyImagesDrink.length + buyImagesDessert.length === 3){
        footerStyle[0].classList.add("order");
        footerStyleSpan.innerHTML = "string";
        
    }});
};
```

I would like to refactor him in these lines:

```js
let combinedVar = buyImages.length + buyImagesDrink.length + buyImagesDessert.length;
var funcOrder = function(selectVar) {
    let selectedVar = selectVar;
    selectVar[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (combinedVar === 3){
        footerStyle[0].classList.add("order");
        footerStyleSpan.innerHTML = "Fechar pedido";
    }
    });
};

var pSelectedDessert = funcOrder(selectedDessert);
var pSelectedDrink = funcOrder(selectedDrink);
var pSelected = funcOrder(selected);

for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    pSelectedDessert();
    pSelectedDrink();
    pSelected();
}
```

```js
Error:
highlight-all.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at funcOrder (highlight-all.js:29)
    at highlight-all.js:37

Error-line:
selectVar[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
```

Problem being: how can I pass a variable to this function, being that it's not yet defined (differed execution).

---

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiLW/q3mwe9ky/13/

Comment: Please, provide a simpler example. This code is hard to read (there are unused variables, it's not well-formatted), and it's bigger than necessary. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I deleted the variables, because it should be of no importance to achieve the actual behavior. The code is big because it's implemented trice, as imperative code. That's exactly what I want to solve.

I give how I want to resolve the verbose problem. And, I highlight the error given by Chrome. 

The indentation is the standard done by vscode, fiddle, and javascript manual. I don't know what you want there. So, I can't help. Be more specific with indentation. Don't you have a place you can indent the code at your preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use closures or to try a functional approach (using the dom and responding to events requires an imperative style anyway).

The first simplification you can make is to use a named function instead of repeating the same function expression thrice - it's exactly the same code, and it doesn't even depend on closure variables with different values.

```
function handleClick() {
    if (buyImages.length + buyImagesDrink.length + buyImagesDessert.length === 3) {
        footerStyle[0].classList.add("order");
        footerStyleSpan.innerHTML = "string";
    }
}
for (var m=0; m < selectedDessert.length; m++) {
    selectedDessert[m].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    selected[m].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    selectedDrink[m].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
}
```

Comment: I used this refactoring, but all things being equal, the compiler do not throw me an error. Although, the application footer stops functioning, as expected.

Well, writing verbose code with repetition is not my thing. This example is pretty trivial in Elm, actually. There are plenty of ways of modifying the DOM, using pure functions; with the bonus of no runtime exceptions - which would save this exact problem I'm having. 

Vuex and Redux both borrow from Elm architecture. You can read it in their documentation; just Ctrl-f "elm". Anyhow, seems like my application is inflexible to changes.

Comment: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/freecodecamp/original/3X/5/3/53ab5fb36a521ec4ef5e3a6d8a7a3a976898af46.png